# Persist page outputcache

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, c#-4.0, outputcache

Is there an option to make page outputcache persist even after IIS restart or web.config modification?

Right now when I upload files the site recompiles and the outputcache resets and get cached upon the next page request.

Comment: sure, but you can't depend on the app memory (where sessions and cache reside by default) as an app reset, will clear both ... [I've written some years ago an answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14047758/28004) that you can take advantage for your problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can implement your own outputcache provider by implementing the OutputCacheProvider:

```
public abstract class OutputCacheProvider : ProviderBase
 {
   public abstract object Get(string key);
   public abstract object Add(string key, object entry, DateTime utcExpiry);
   public abstract void Set(string key, object entry, DateTime utcExpiry);
   public abstract void Remove(string key);
 }
```

For further reading and how to implement you can read: [creating-a-custom-output-cache-provider](http://www.drdobbs.com/windows/creating-a-custom-output-cache-provider/232601001)

More resources to read: [scottgu extensible-output-caching-with-asp-net-4-vs-2010-and-net-4-0-series](https://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/extensible-output-caching-with-asp-net-4-vs-2010-and-net-4-0-series)